# Refer to Object from server response

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

On the server there is (as I understand it) an object. It has 2 values ​​- the text and the color of this text. So - I need to get this text and color. At the moment everything is displayed together - TextView is passed the value [{"text": "WE RETURN 10% BONUSES", "textColor": "# 4c82a6"}] ,.

I need to get these values ​​separately

```
"tag": [
        {
            "text": "ВЕРНЕМ 10% БОНУСАМИ",
            "textColor": "#4c82a6"
        }
    ],
```

Model

```
public class Item {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @SerializedName("isFavorite")
    @Expose
    private boolean isFavorite;
    @SerializedName("prices")
    @Expose
    private Prices prices;
    @SerializedName("full_set_prices")
    @Expose
    private Object fullSetPrices;
    @SerializedName("isBestPrice")
    @Expose
    private boolean isBestPrice;
    @SerializedName("tag")
    @Expose
    private Object tag;
    @SerializedName("articul")
    @Expose
    private String articul;
    @SerializedName("rating")
    @Expose
    private double rating;
    @SerializedName("numberOfReviews")
    @Expose
    private int numberOfReviews;
    @SerializedName("statusText")
    @Expose
    private String statusText;
    @SerializedName("isAvailable")
    @Expose
    private boolean isAvailable;
    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    private List<String> images = null;
    @SerializedName("categoryId")
    @Expose
    private String categoryId;
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    
    public boolean isIsFavorite() {
        return isFavorite;
    }
    
    
    public Prices getPrices() {
        return prices;
    }
    
    public Object getFullSetPrices() {
        return fullSetPrices;
    }
    
    public boolean isIsBestPrice() {
        return isBestPrice;
    }
    
    public Object getTag() {
        return tag;
    }
    
    public void setTag(Object tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
    
    public String getArticul() {
        return articul;
    }
    
    public void setArticul(String articul) {
        this.articul = articul;
    }
    
    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    
    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    
    public int getNumberOfReviews() {
        return numberOfReviews;
    }
    
    public void setNumberOfReviews(int numberOfReviews) {
        this.numberOfReviews = numberOfReviews;
    }
    
    public String getStatusText() {
        return statusText;
    }
    
    public void setStatusText(String statusText) {
        this.statusText = statusText;
    }
    
    public boolean isIsAvailable() {
        return isAvailable;
    }
    
    public void setIsAvailable(boolean isAvailable) {
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    }
    
    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
    
    public void setImages(List<String> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
    
    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }
    
    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another POJO for the tag instead of using `Object`.

```
public class Item {
  ...
  @SerializedName("tag")
  @Expose
  private Tag tag;
  ...
}

public class Tag {

  @SerializedName("text")
  @Expose
  private String text;

  @SerializedName("textColor")
  @Expose
  private String textColor;

}
```

Then you can access the new values with `item.getTag().getText()`. Or if you'd rather make it appear that the two `Tag` fields are part of `Item`, you can create methods that delegate to `Tag`:

```
public class Item {
  ...
  public String getText() {
    return this.tag.getText();
  }

  public String getTextColor() {
    return this.tag.getTextColor();
  }
  ...
}
```